# Lack of reliability "in" or "of"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Researchers' communities think bananas have a lack of reliability.

How should I say this?

> 1. There was a lack of reliability **in** the bananas, from the researchers' communities.
> 2. There was a lack of reliability **of** the bananas, in the researchers' communities.

Or none of the above?

Comment: Are bananas unreliable test subjects in an experiment or is their availability unreliable?

Comment: Bananas are unreliable test subjects.

Answer (score 2):

Between those two choices I would have to go with "of", as reliability is a concept possessed by the banana as a whole rather than an ingredient contained by the banana.

However, the sentence would benefit greatly from re-wording to eliminate the passive voice and its unnecessarily complex structure:

> The bananas were unreliable in the researchers' communities.
>
> The researchers' communities felt that the bananas could not be relied upon.
>
> The bananas had no reliability as far as the researchers' communities were concerned.

Comment: The first option sounds a bit strange: "The bananas were unreliable in the researchers' communities." Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: It would probably be better put as "The bananas in the researchers' communities were unreliable."

Comment: +1, but you failed to motivate your choosing "bananas" as from the OP's first example over "babanas" from the second.

Comment: I thought about putting in *"Where the heck are our babanas?!" was a constant refrain from the research community*, but ultimately decided against it.